# Can authors see changes in NeurIPS reviewer scores after the rebuttal period ends? (openreview platform)

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

Reviewers can change their score during the rebuttal phase and these changes are visible to the authors, other reviewers, ACs SACs, and PCs.

I know that the reviewers can also change their scores after the rebuttal period ends. My question is, are any score changes after the rebuttal period visible to the authors before the final decision notification?

MY questions is specifically about NeurIPS and the openreview platform.